Can the list of related questions be improved?
A few similar or duplicate questions appear every now and then. It is not easy to spot those questions unless you have seen them before or you do a deliberate search. Can the list of 10 related questions be tuned to focus more on the Chinese characters?
For example, if the question title is "What is the difference in use between 以及, 和 and 与?". Instead of listing question titles starting with "What is the difference..." and "Difference between...". It would be more relevant to pull out question titles such as "...与，和...", "... 和 and 及 ...", etc.
This will make it easier and faster for us to spot duplicates and flag accordingly. It will also be much more easier for people to read across similar content, since the Chinese characters are usually the key to the question.
Further, can this search be made insensitive to whether they are traditional or simplified Chinese?

Good point. I will email the SE staff and ask if this can be done. I will let you know here once they respond.

See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190243/related-questions-irrelevant-on-asian-language-sites and vote up if you agree
